# npm error code EPEERINVALID while installing mongoose-auto-increment and mongoose-simpledb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have encountered the following error while installing npm package  mongoose-auto-increment and mongoose-simpledb both globally and locally.

The Error are as follows

**mongoose-auto-increment**

```
   npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency mongoose@~4.0.0       included from mongoose-auto-increment will no
   npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
   npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
   npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
   npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose-auto-increment"
   npm ERR! node v0.12.4
   npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
   npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

   npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongoose does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoose-auto-increment@4.0.0 wants mongoose@~4.0.0

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /Users/febinp/Downloads/Shubham_application/Project/npm-debug.log
```

**mongoose-simpledb**

```
   npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
   npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose-simpledb"
   npm ERR! node v0.12.4
   npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
   npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
   npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongoose does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoose-auto-increment@4.0.0 wants mongoose@~4.0.0
   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoose-simpledb@4.0.3 wants mongoose@~3.8.18

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /Users/febinp/Downloads/Shubham_application/Project/npm-debug.log
```

My `Package.json` is as follows

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
         "async": "^1.4.0",
         "ejs": "~0.8.4",
         "grunt": "0.4.2",
         "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
         "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
         "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
         "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
         "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
         "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
         "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
         "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
         "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
         "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
         "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
         "include-all": "~0.1.3",
         "mongoose": "^4.1.0",
         "mongoose-acl": "^0.2.3",
         "mongoose-unique-validator": "^0.4.1",
         "passport-local-mongoose": "^1.0.1",
         "rc": "~0.5.0",
         "sails": "~0.11.0",
         "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  },
 "scripts": {
         "debug": "node debug app.js",
         "start": "node app.js"
 },
 "main": "app.js",
 "repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "git://github.com/febinp/ZATASA.git"
},
 "author": "XYZ",
 "license": ""
}
```

Can somebody help me as to why I am getting this error and what is the workaround?

Comment: try changing in package.json "mongoose": "~4.0.0". Let me know if works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `package.json` mongoose have a higher version 4.0.0. But `mongoose-simpledb` wants mongoose@~3.8.18.
2. `mongoose-simpledb` includes it's dependency `mongoose-auto-increment`. If you explicitly declare the _id field on your schema as type Number then simpledb will automatically invoke the mongoose-auto-increment plugin for that model.

Example from documentation itself:

```
exports.schema = {
    _id: Number, // Causes simpledb to auto-increment _id for new documents.
    creator: { type: Number, ref: 'User' }
};
```

I have tried changing the package.json to this and it worked:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
         "async": "^1.4.0",
         "ejs": "~0.8.4",
         "grunt": "0.4.2",
         "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
         "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
         "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
         "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
         "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
         "grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
         "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
         "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
         "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
         "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
         "grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
         "include-all": "~0.1.3",
         "mongoose": "~3.8.18",
         "mongoose-simpledb": "~4.0.3",
         "mongoose-acl": "^0.2.3",
         "mongoose-unique-validator": "^0.4.1",
         "passport-local-mongoose": "^1.0.1",
         "rc": "~0.5.0",
         "sails": "~0.11.0",
         "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  },
 "scripts": {
         "debug": "node debug app.js",
         "start": "node app.js"
 },
 "main": "app.js",
 "repository": {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "git://github.com/febinp/ZATASA.git"
},
"author": "XYZ",
 "license": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve it using these command :

```bash
npm i --legacy-peer-deps mongoose-auto-increment
```